# Create textbox dynamically in Matlab

Tags: matlab, textbox, dynamically-generated

I am using GUIde to allow the user to select files from his/her hard drive, load it into a list and populate the names and content of the loaded files into text boxes.

So far I am good up to loading the files into the list. I really find a way to create the appropriate number of text boxes based on the number of files loaded. Below is my script:

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

% Get file file names from loading directory/folder
filename= uigetfile('*.dat', 'Multiselect','on');

% Show all profi files names in the listbox
set(handles.listbox1,'String',filename);

% Reset selection for all loaded files
for k = 1:length(filename)
set(handles.listbox1,'Value',k);

empty_panel = get(handles.uipanel2,'Tag');
number = length(filename);
for jj = 1:number
    textEl(jj) = uicontrol('Parent', empty_panel, 'Style', ... 
                'text','test','Position', [0 (jj-1)*30, 100, 20]);
end
```

I have previously created a panel (uipanel2), a pushbutton (pushbutton1) and a listbox (listbox1). I receive the below error message:

```
 Error using uicontrol
 Invalid convenience arg handle

 Error in plot_profi_V2>pushbutton1_Callback (line 124)
     textEl(jj) = uicontrol('Parent', empty_panel, 'Style', ...
                'text','test');%'Position', [0 (i-1)*30, 100, 20]);
```

Comment: `'test'` does not have a valid property name associated with it.

Comment: @excaza 'test' is is associated with the style "text" or did i misunderstand your question?

Comment: That's not valid syntax

Comment: @excaza what is the correct syntax to make it work?

Comment: Either remove it or actually specify whatever property you're trying to set it to

Answer (score 0):

After two days I found the issue, below is the script for future reference:

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

% Get file file names from loading directory/folder
filename= uigetfile('*.dat', 'Multiselect','on');

% Show all profi files names in the listbox
set(handles.listbox1,'String',filename);

% Reset selection for all loaded files
for k = 1:length(filename)
set(handles.listbox1,'Value',k);

empty_panel = get(handles.uipanel2,'Tag');
number = length(filename);
for jj = 1:number
    textEl(jj)= uicontrol(handles.uipanel2,'Style','text','String',filename{jj}, ...
                     'Units','normalized','Position',[jj/10-0.1 0.9 0.1 0.1]);
end
```

Comment: Why did it take two days to find the issue I gave you less than an hour after you asked the question?

Comment: Because your reply was more than vague even after I asked for guidance. But the most important is that i managed to make it work and it is now available online for whoever else.

Comment: How is "specify the property you're trying to set" vague?